# Broadcasting video iphone to Wowza server using AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, avcapturesession, avassetwriter, broadcasting, wowza-transcoder

I am Developing live broadcasting feature, i have built Custom camera to shoot video using `AVCaptureSession`, and we have Wowza server for broadcasting,

So my Question is how to Encode Video  from `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate`,`AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` and send to Server, I found many libraries, but not suitable for our application, they provide their own UI, Can any one Suggest any other library or Step by step Integration

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [AVAssetWriterInput
init mediaType:outputSettings:sourceFormatHint:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetWriterInput_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAssetWriterInput/initWithMediaType:outputSettings:sourceFormatHint:) method?. This takes a dictionary with the desired settings. From the docs..."Specify a dictionary containing the settings used for encoding the media appended to the output. You may pass nil for this parameter if you do not want the appended samples to be re-encoded."

Comment: Can you Explain more, Where can i use this method, or can u paste some Demo code

Comment: I would read through this https://www.objc.io/issues/23-video/capturing-video/ and check out the demo project from the article here https://github.com/objcio/VideoCaptureDemo

Comment: after encode video to h264 and ACC how to send video to Server for broadCasting we have used Wowza server

Comment: Im afraid I can't help you with that portion. I assume you are going to need to create multiple smaller files. I would break up the live stream into 5 second sections using multiple AVAssetWriters. Then upload them via HTTP to a Wowza server. The Wowza server could then create the output stream for all your other devices. Thats just a educated guess. I would look at Wowzas docs. I would think they have some type of demo.